# How to access conv2d layers in resnet50?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am using a Resnet50 model and want to visualize the features of certain conv2d layer after forwarding an image through the network, but somehow I am not able to access the inner conv2d layers in the Bottleneck blocks.

My code so far:

```
def forward_res(model, conv_layer, x): 
    count = 0
    for child in model.children(): #outer layers
        x = child(x)
        if isinstance(child, nn.Conv2d):
            if count == conv_layer:
                return x
            count = count+1
            
        if isinstance(child, nn.Sequential):
            for bottleneck in child: 
                for lay in bottleneck.children(): #inner layers
                    x = lay(x)
                    if isinstance(lay, nn.Conv2d):
                        if count == conv_layer:
                            return x
                        count = count + 1
```

When I try to use my code like this, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 1 3 1 1, expected
> input[1, 1, 512, 512] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Can somebody help me how to access the inner conv2d layers of a Renset model? Or tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Watch out for your input tensor's shape. If you have a single layer as your input, you could duplicate the layer three times on the 2nd dim: `x.repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)`.